# Сollision detection c++

Tags: c++, collision-detection, glm

In the cube class I have its position and rotation. Also I have a collision check function:

```
bool is_collision(voxel collis)
 {
     if (collis.position.x > position.x || collis.position.y > position.y || collis.position.z > position.z)
     {
         if (collis.position.x - position.x <= 1 && collis.position.y - position.y <= 1 && collis.position.z - position.z <= 1)
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     else if (collis.position.x < position.x || collis.position.y < position.y || collis.position.z < position.z)
     {
         if (position.x - collis.position.x <= 1 && position.y - collis.position.y <= 1 && position.z - collis.position.z <= 1)
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

It accepts another cube to be collided with. But so far, this function does not take into account the rotation of the object.
I also use glm.
How do I need to change this code?